# How to adjust the font size

Tags: html, css, email, font-size

I've been trying to change the font under the "Future 1", 
you can see the code here;
but if I change the font, changes doesn't apply.

http://jsfiddle.net/b5fMe/15/

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Were you trying to change the font-size from your `style` tag or the `style` attribute on its parent `td` or the `p` tag? Also why do you have all this styling directly on elements with their `style` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You font-size settings are all being overidden by inline 'style' declarations in the HTML code e,g, `id="topbar" style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;` - these are applied *after* your CSS.

Comment: does that mean that I have to delete the inline style?

Comment: Yes, then adjust the css in the head section accordingly. Better still, put them all in a separate file and import it into your main template or html pages - this makes maintenance much simpler. An inline style is only necessary when you have a single occurrence or exception to your main styles.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the font size is set as a style attribute on the parent `<td>`.  I've [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5fMe/16/) to show it with a 12px font size instead.

The changed block of code is as follows with `font-size` set to 12px:

```
<td class="content threecol first" style="font-size: 12px;line-height: 1.4em;color: #444;width: 25%;padding-right: 20px;padding-left: 0;padding-top: 20px;border-right: 1px solid #ccc;border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(204 , 204, 204);">
```

Comment: ok i will try this one and see if that works, thanks for updaing th fiddle ;-)